# Installing RVM on Ubuntu 11.4 error

Tags: ubuntu, rvm

I've followed the installation procedure as in RVM website(https://rvm.io/rvm/install/) but it didn't installed on my ubuntu machine. I tried it from my /home/user1 directory.

The /.rvm directory itself not created. It didn't say any error as well.

The following script is dumped when I ran (curl -s https://rvm.io/install/rvm).

Any help on this?

```
user1@ubuntu:~$ (curl -s https://rvm.io/install/rvm)
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s extglob
PS4="+ \${BASH_SOURCE##\${rvm_path:-}} : \${FUNCNAME[0]:+\${FUNCNAME[0]}()}  \${LINENO} > "
export PS4
set -o errtrace
set -o errexit

log()  { printf "$*\n" ; return $? ;  }

fail() { log "\nERROR: $*\n" ; exit 1 ; }

usage()
{
  printf "

Usage

  rvm-installer [options] [action]

Options

  --branch <name>               - Install RVM head, from named branch
  --version <head|latest|x.y.z> - Install RVM version [head|latest|x.y.z]
  --trace                       - used to debug the installer script

Actions

  help - Display CLI help (this output)

"
}
.....
....
.....
.
.....
.....
.....
.....


# No matter which one we are doing we install the same way, using the RVM
#   installer script.
flags=()
if (( rvm_trace_flag == 1 ))
then
  flags+=("--trace")
fi

if (( rvm_debug_flag == 1 ))
then
  flags+=("--debug")
fi

chmod +x ./scripts/install

# Now we run the RVM installer.
./scripts/install ${flags[*]} --prefix "$rvm_prefix" --path "$rvm_path"

user1@ubuntu:~$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the 'bash' command. Copy paste this (all):

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash
```

Comment: Thanks. Now it's installed properly.